# Displaying content of field other than text using JavaScript

Tags: splistitem

I'm still struggling with SP.js handling of special fields, i.e, computed, lookup, Boolean, MultiChoice, on the OUTPUT side.

When building the CAML I know how to add value type tag to be able to query the data in these special fields. What I have not figured out is what to add on the output to get these special fields to display.

For example: the CAML query uses http to find all records that contain "http".

And U2U shows the contents of the field as Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUrlValue.

My  output uses `listItem.get_item('URL')` to display but fails. I suspect because I need to convert it with some sort `.get_URlValue()` but I can not find specifically what to use.

Where can I find what I need to add to the `listItem.get_item()` in order to convert the data into something that can be displayed.

I'm also struggling with fields that U2U show as :

```
System.String[]
and TaxonomyFields System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]
```